# C# actionresult filter using array or list

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, list, controller

I feel like I am either close or way way off.  Stumbling though MVC5 C# webapp, have read some great help given however I just can't seem to find the exact syntax that gets me a result.

In my controller I am trying to filter my results based on a concatenation of strings (so basically I can convert it to an array or list - or leave it as is. Not sure).  The array/list can be 1 to 14 variables.  Controller per below:

```
public ActionResult Result(string Person)
{
   Hierarchy h = db.Hierarchies.First(i => i.People == Person);
   if (h == null)
   {
        return HttpNotFound();
   }
   List<string> list = h.Hierarchy1.Split('/').ToList();

   //Trial 1
   var dat = from p in list where db.Hierarchies.Contains(p.list) select p; //

   //Trial 2
   var dat = db.Hierarchies.Where(s => s.People.Contains(list));//

   return View("Result", dat);
}
```

Basically Person is first looked up in table hierarchy, and from this I get a paternal list (hierarchy1) separated by '/'.  From this list I am trying to filter out every row not in the list of hierarchy table.  The table contains more info per row(date of birth, age, eye colour etc).  All names are unique so no issue with errors from this.

I have had success with easier searches like everyone with blue eyes, but when there are multiple searches I can't seem to get it to add up.

I have tried it as an array, but my latest reading seems to say a list is better to store my string.split.

Hierarchy1 string can look like:

Chris John Wilks/David John Wilks/Craig Ramsey Wilks/Michael Wilks

Hierarchy Table example:

- Headers - Hierarchy1;    Person;       DOB;       Age;Eyes;Hair;
- Data - Per Hierarchy1 above;Michael Wilks;05/02/1980;37; Blue;Brown

Essentially I am trying to get a list I can loop through on the view (foreach) per below based on data above:

- Chris John Wilks DOB;Age;Eyes;Hair; (Great Grand father)
- David John Wilks DOB;Age;Eyes;Hair; (Grand father)
- Craig Ramsey Wilks DOB;Age;Eyes;Hair; (Father)
- Michael Wilks DOB;Age;Eyes;Hair; (Son)

etc

On Trial 1 error at list here ---> Contains(p.***list***)

On Trial 2 error at list here ---> Contains(***list***)

So I could be wayyyy off on what is the right format but I have been searching the internet and SO, this was some of the best I could piece together.

Appreciate everyone and anyone's help and assistance.

***UPDATE*** 18/09/2017
I have given up on my first attempts and I think I have found a better keyword to search by = "LINQ" this is getting me some better results which I think is pointing me correctly to an answer.

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list = h.Hierarchy1.Split('/').ToList();

        foreach (string k in list)
        {
            IQueryable<Hierarchy> TQuery = from a in db.Hierarchies
                                           where (a.People == k)
                                           select a;
        }
        return View("Result", TQuery.ToList());
```

So now it looks like my query works but my "return view" is showing an error on "**TQuery**".ToList.
My assumption is because I called it within the foreach loop rather than outside so I need to figure out how to get it out without it throwing up errors.  Then post that I will run to see if it actually works.

I still think there is a way to do it without the foreach loop but it escapes me

***UPDATE*** 19/09/2017 - **Working Result**
So I managed to get it working as a IQueryable and without a foreach - which I think means it is a fairly optimal solution - the People in the list is un-ordered at this point but I think that is minor.

So in full it is:

```
    public ActionResult Result(string Person)
    {
        Hierarchy h = db.Hierarchies.First(i => i.People == Person);
        if (h == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        int lvl = h.Level;
        var list = new string[lvl];
        list = h.Hierarchy1.Split('/');

        IQueryable<Hierarchy> TQuery = from a in db.Hierarchies
                                       where list.Contains(a.People)
                                       select a;
        return View("Result", TQuery.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Contains method needs a string as parameter, why are you passing list (List of strings)? have you tried make a ForEach loop over list?

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan - yes I had started with a foreach loop and did not have much success.  I think when searching I was using the wrong key words.  I seem to be having more luck with "LINQ" which I assume is important.  I will update my post with what I have found - still not working but I think I am close

Comment: There is a problem in foreach loop. TQuery is only returning what is found in the last item of the list. Initiate TQuery with null before the loop and add the result to it. add db.Hierarchies.Where(p=>p.Poeple == k) to TQuery for each k.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan - Thanks for working through some of the issues with me.  I think this is pretty much fixed as far as my original SO question.  Appreciate the brainstorming.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan - just tried your solution (I am missing something).  It only displays the last person in the list.  so obviously as I go through the loop it is not saving correctly.  Your solution is looking better as it would order the list I think.  But I will plow on with what I have so far working and figure the finer details later.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    public ActionResult Result(string Person)
{
    Hierarchy h = db.Hierarchies.First(i => i.People == Person);
    if (h == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    int lvl = h.Level;
    var list = new string[lvl];
    list = h.Hierarchy1.Split('/');

    IQueryable<Hierarchy> TQuery = from a in db.Hierarchies
                                   where list.Contains(a.People)
                                   select a;
    return View("Result", TQuery.ToList());
}
```

I probably should add - by luck I did store the number of people per Hierarchy1 as "Level" in the table so that gave me an array size "lvl".

I still think @AryanFirouzyan was pointing to a better solution but since I have spent 10 hours on this I think I need to move onto my next problem :)

Comment: Adding to this answer - I found out how to order this.  Turned out to be fairly obvious in the end again because I had the level value for each.  Before "select a", insert "orderby a.Level" and it came out sorted in order smallest level to largest. So I guess key to this was storing the position in the "hierarchy" where the person belonged in relation to the first relative recorded.